# How can i get all active users in channel pubnub in unity3d

Tags: pubnub

I'd like to get all active users subscriber in channel for unity3d.
Is there a way to do that with pubnub in unity3d?

Answer (score 2):

## PubNub Unity SDK Presence - HereNow

To get all active subscribers on a channel, you just call `HereNow`.

```
pubnub.HereNow()
    .Channels(new List<string>(){
        "my_channel"
    })
    .ChannelGroups(new List<string>() {
        "my_channel_group"
    })
    .IncludeState(true)
    .IncludeUUIDs(true)
    .Async((result, status) => {
        if (status.Error) {
            Debug.Log(string.Format("HereNow Error: {0} {1} {2}", status.StatusCode, status.ErrorData, status.Category));
        } else {               
            Debug.Log(string.Format("DateTime {0}, In Example, Channels: {1} {2}", DateTime.UtcNow , result.TotalChannels, result.TotalOccupancy));
        }
        Debug.Log(status.Error);
    });
```

If you want to know if there are any subscribers that are no longer active (offline), you need to look into the new feature (beta at this time) called [*Objects* which includes *Spaces*, *Users* and *Memberships*](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/unity3d-c-sharp/api-reference-objects).

### Objects

[Objects Tutorial](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/unity3d-c-sharp/pubnub-objects)
Objects provides easy-to-use, serverless storage for data you need to build innovative, reliable, scalable Chat applications. Use Object information across your connected experience features. You can easily save, read, update, and delete information about your application users, shared communication spaces, and their relationships, without the need to stand up a database. Simply build and go.

> **NOTE**: Objects is an optional feature, currently in a BETA release—you can
> use your own user management system, and simply use the usual publish
> and subscribe. If you'd like to use PubNub's serverless storage,
> Objects provides a full-featured solution.

Comment: I tried use the hereNow always return 
(DateTime 1/21/2020 5:04:26 PM, In Example, Channels: 0 0 )
result.TotalChannels = 0 
result.TotalOccupancy = 0

Comment: Did you enable Presence on your key set in your PubNub account?

Comment: Yes i enable it , but Presence automatically turn off after refresh page. 
Anyway today i tried read a lot api and i found how can i read the TotalOccupancy without use herenow(). After pubnub.Subscribe() use .WithPresence() then use 
this code inside SubscribeCallback

if (mea.PresenceEventResult != null)
   {
    print (mea.PresenceEventResult.Occupancy);
   }

Comment: Well, enabling Presence on your key set doesn't disable unless you go in and disable it again. But I see what you are saying here. You can enable a subscriber to receive presence events on a channel by using the `withPresence` API in your `subscribe` call. So yes, you do have that correct. But to clarify, that only affects whether that client subscriber receives those presence events and not whether others do or not and not whether PubNub will publish presences events or not. More comments on your answer below.

Comment: yesterday i get around 10K devices connection in one channel and Occupancy does not work - but when i get in first day 300 devices is work fine! 
So this problem because i use free plan ? does i need to upgrade to stander plan  ?

Comment: 10K devices, you are probably going to hit Free tier limits pretty fast. But a channel with that many devices will likely need some best practices guidance. Please contact support to get in touch with our onboarding team who can provide these insights.

Answer (score 1):

I found Solution read total Occupancy but i am not sure if total Occupancy for all channels or one channel and is realtime or not

```
    pubnub.SubscribeCallback += (sender, e) =>
    {
        SubscribeEventEventArgs mea = e as SubscribeEventEventArgs;


        if (mea.Status != null)
        {
            if (mea.Status.Category.Equals(PNStatusCategory.PNConnectedCategory))
            {
                pubnub.Publish()
                    .Channel("RoomName")
                    .Async((result, status) =>
                    {
                        if (!status.Error)
                        {
                            Debug.Log(string.Format("DateTime {0}, In Publish Example, Timetoken: {1}", DateTime.UtcNow, result.Timetoken));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Debug.Log(status.Error);
                            Debug.Log(status.ErrorData.Info);
                        }
                    });


            }

        if (mea.PresenceEventResult != null)
            {
            print(mea.PresenceEventResult.Occupancy);
            }

   };
    pubnub.Subscribe()
    .Channels(new List<string>(){
    "RoomName"
    })
    .WithPresence() // don't forget this  
    .Execute();
```

Comment: That `presence callback` in your `addListener` code is realtime presence events and is per channel and presence events have when anyone *joins* or *leaves* a channels (also for `timeout` and `state-change` events). When you call HereNow, you can list 1 or more channels. But if you just want to get a total occupancy and a list of all subscribers when you join a channel, call `HereNow` and listen for presence events to update occupancy with each presence event (join, leave timeout). (running out of characters in the comment. To be continued...)

Comment: Hope that is helpful. If not, please submit details to [PubNub Support](https://support.pubnub.com) including a link to this post so we can post any updates back here. If it is possible to do so, please [enable PubNub Unity SDK v4 client logging](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/unity3d-c-sharp/pubnub-c-sharp-sdk-troubleshooting-guide), reproduce the issue, and send us the entire log file (as an attachment). The data captured will be very valuable for troubleshooting the issue.

Comment: @CraigConover i tired to use joins or leaves and mea.PresenceEventResult.Occupancy it is work but is not correct, i have 7 devices (3 ios , 4 android ) when players join or leaves not always call joins or leaves! and result of players count not correct even when i put Occupancy in update function. 
Also HereNow i tried a lot but always return Channels: 0 0 , where ever but HereNow is not helpful for me because i want to display Counts Of Player in Real Time.

What do you suggest I do to get players of count in real time ?

Comment: @CraigConover
Some information about the devices Iphone x ios 13.3 Iphone 6 ios 13 Ipad pro 11 inch Android 6.0.1 Android 7.0 Android 7.1.1 Android 9 

The issue this event (join and leaves ) not always call.

Comment: The event (joins or leaves) is work fine in android and ios, but my problem was i forget change UUID for each device, right now joins and leaves is helpful for me and work is good, @CraigConover thank you.

Comment: Great, be sure that each device has its own UUID and that it reuses that UUID for consistent presence, and billing, behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

(i) Use the Presence feature from PubNub to get the list of users currently subscribed to a channel by calling the HereNow API call. You will need to enable Presence on your keyset in the PubNub Admin Dashboard.

(ii) Use PubNub Objects to store a list of channels (called Spaces in Objects speak), Users and Memberships of users in those channels and update that info as users join or leave channels and always fetch a list of users in a channel from the Memberships object. You will need to enable Objects on your keyset in the PubNub Admin Dashboard.